# How can I update my Window controls from an STA Thread when calling from an async operation?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

My server application is a WPF project which uses asynchronous callbacks to handle client requests and to send responses back to the client.

The server is to update its database based on the data received from the client and, depending on the nature of that data, push an alert through its own UI to reflect the new alert.

When it comes time to update the UI, I'm getting an error saying that the calling thread must be an STA thread or some such thing.

How can I make sure that the thread that's trying to update the UI is properly set up to do it without causing errors?

See below for all of my code and commentry about what the code is doing.

#### Client Helper

The ClientHelper class is a wrapper for client requests.

```
public class ClientHelper
{
    private readonly TcpClient _Client;
    private readonly byte[] _Buffer;

    public Client(TcpClient client)
    {
        _Client = client;
        int BufferSize = _Client.ReceiveBufferSize;
        _Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    }

    public TcpClient TcpClient
    {
        get { return _Client; }
    }
    public byte[] Buffer
    {
        get { return _Buffer; }
    }
    public NetworkStream NetworkStream
    {
        get { return TcpClient.GetStream(); }
    }
}
```

### FooServer

The server uses a TcpListener that's running on its own thread so as to avoid locking the UI.

```
public class FooServer
{
    private TcpListener Svr;

    public void StartServer()
    {
        Thread ListenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            Svr = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 13000);
            Svr.Start();

            Svr.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptClientCallback, null);
        }));
        ListenerThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        ListenerThread.IsBackground = true;

        ListenerThread.Start();
    }
```

The server keeps track of its connected clients by maintaining a list of them.

```
    private List<Client> ConnectedClients = new List<Client>();
    private void AcceptClientCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        TcpClient Client;
        try
        {
            Client = Svr.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnError(Svr, ex);
            //Svr.Stop();
            return;
        }

        Svr.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptClientCallback, null);

        ClientHelper _Client = new ClientHelper(Client);
        ConnectedClients.Add(_Client);
        NetworkStream Stream = _Client.NetworkStream;
        Stream.BeginRead(_Client.Buffer, 0, _Client.Buffer.Length, ReadCallback, _Client);
    }
```

After it reads the client's data, the server executes functions that manipulate the data and forward the alert to the UI. `HandleClientData` is where all of this starts. Its the last read that the server does.

```
    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ClientHelper Client = result.AsyncState as ClientHelper;
        if (Client != null)
        {
            NetworkStream Stream = Client.NetworkStream;
            int Read;
            try
            {
                Read = Stream.EndRead(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnError(Client, ex);
                return;
            }

            if (Read == 0)
            {
                Client.TcpClient.Close();
                ConnectedClients.Remove(Client);
                return;
            }

            byte[] Data = new byte[Read];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(Client.Buffer, 0, Data, 0, Read); // copy read data to the client's buffer
            Stream.BeginRead(Client.Buffer, 0, Read, ReadCallback, Client); // read data
            HandleClientData(Stream, Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Client.Buffer, 0, Data.Length));
        }
    }

    private void HandleClientData(NetworkStream stream, string data)
    {
        byte[] value = null;
        try
        {
            string[] Data = data.Split(',');

            if (String.Equals(Data[0], "GetAllFoo"))
            {
                value = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetFoo());
            }
            else if (String.Equals(Data[0], "GetAFoo"))
            {
                int FooId;
                Int32.TryParse(Data[1], out FooId);

                value = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetFoo(FooId));
            }
            else
            {
                // Update the Foo in the database to reflect the latest state of every component.
                UpdateFoo(Data);

                // evaluate the data for a fault and raise an alert if there's something wrong.
                if (!EvaluateFooData(Data[1]))
                {
                    AddAlert();
                }

                value = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SUCCESS,The Foo was successfully updated.|");
            }

            stream.Write(value, 0, value.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string Error = String.Format("ERR,{0}", ex.Message);
            byte[] ErrorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Error);
            stream.Write(ErrorBytes, 0, ErrorBytes.Length);

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

`EvaluateFooData` checks the client data against acceptable norms and adds any deviation to a list that gets read by `AddAlert` below which adds the alerts to the database.

```
public void AddAlert()
{
    ApplicationDbContext Context = new ApplicationDbContext();

    foreach (Alert Alert in Alerts)
    {
        Context.Alerts.Add(Alert);
    }
    Context.SaveChanges();

    OnRaiseAlert();
}

public event EventHandler RaiseAlert;
protected virtual void OnRaiseAlert()
{
    RaiseAlert?.Invoke(this, null);
}
```

Using the EventHandler which is registered on the UI, the server pushes an alert to the UI:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Server.RaiseAlert += Server_RaiseAlert;
}
private void Server_RaiseAlert(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationDbContext Context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var Alerts = Context.Alerts.Where(x => x.IsResolved == false).ToList();

    StackPanel FooStackPanel = new StackPanel();
    spFoo.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => { FooStackPanel = spFoo; }));

    if (Alerts != null && Alerts.Count >= 1)
    {
        foreach (Alert Alert in Alerts)
        {
            Button Btn = (Button)FooStackPanel.Children[FooId];
            Btn.Style = FindResource("FooAlertIcon") as Style;
        }
    }
}
```

`Server_RaiseAlert` updates the UI by changing the style of buttons that were created during initialization of the Window so that those buttons now indicate a problem with that Foo. The basic concept is green = good, red = bad.

Comment: You have to be more specific about error. Which error and at which line?

Comment: STA threads must have a message pump, I don't see one in the thread you create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do everything that manipulates UI elements inside the Dispatcher Action:

```
private void Server_RaiseAlert(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var alerts = context.Alerts.Where(x => x.IsResolved == false).ToList();

    if (alerts.Count > 0)
    {
        spFoo.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            foreach (var alert in alerts)
            {
                var button = (Button)spFoo.Children[FooId];
                button.Style = FindResource("FooAlertIcon") as Style;
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Note however that from your question it isn't clear where `FooId` comes from.

Comment: `Note however that from your question it isn't clear where FooId comes from.` That's not a problem. Just my paste was incomplete

Comment: You, sir, deserve so many more than just 1 Useful vote on this answer. I can't tell you how thrilled I am that it works now! Thank you so very much.