# Using async in static context to update the UI is not working

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, sta

I am using the following code

```
public static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Task timerTask = Program.RunPeriodically(() => { Program.SendNotification($"foo", BalloonIcon.Info); }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), tokenSource.Token);
        timerTask.Wait(tokenSource.Token);
    }

    private static void SendNotification(string message, BalloonIcon balloonIcon)
    {
        new TaskbarIcon().ShowBalloonTip("Title", message, balloonIcon);
    }

    private static async Task RunPeriodically(Action action, TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            action();
            await Task.Delay(interval, token);
        }
    }
}
```

and what I want to do is run the method `SendNotification` every 10 seconds. To achieve this, I call the method `RunPeriodically`.

However, the call to `SendNotifcation` throws an `InvalidOperationException`, saying:

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

I also tried [some suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44315471/7571171) using the `Dispatcher` like this

```
private static void SendNotification(string message, BalloonIcon balloonIcon)
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        new TaskbarIcon().ShowBalloonTip("Title", message, balloonIcon);
    });
}
```

but it did not make a change.

My only guess is that the code does not work because it is not called from a `Window` instance, but rather in a static context of a class that has no `this.Dispatcher`, but I do not know how to make it work in this case and I appreciate any help.

Comment: You *don't* have a console application if you have a UI to update. Both Windows Forms and WPF applications start from a Main function, even though it isn't apparent. That doesn't make them *console* applications

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, you are right. Thank you. I will edit the question title to clear that misconception up.

Comment: As for your specific problem, just *don't* update the UI from another thread. Use async/await to *await* anything that runs in the background and update the UI after the call to `await`. `await` doesn't make anything run in the background. It *awaits* for a background task/job to finish, then returns to the UI thread. You don't need dispatchers and `Invoke()` when you are already on the UI thread

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so when would be the appropriate place to call the method? After `timerTask.Wait(tokenSource.Token);`?

Comment: Looks like an XY question. When all you need is a windowless program to show notifications, google for that. Don't invent your own.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes, it does look like that, because I stripped my code down as much as I could, to provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The actual code does do a few more things, but they are not relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this slightly modified example below works pretty well for me.

Hope it helps!

```
public static class Program
{
    private static NotifyIcon notifyIcon;

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        notifyIcon.Icon = SystemIcons.Information;
        notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Title";
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;

        Task timerTask = Program.RunPeriodically(() => { Program.SendNotification(DateTime.Now.ToString(), ToolTipIcon.Info); }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), tokenSource.Token);
        timerTask.Wait(tokenSource.Token);
    }

    private static void SendNotification(string message, ToolTipIcon balloonIcon)
    {
        notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = balloonIcon;
        notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = message;
        notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(500);
    }

    private static async Task RunPeriodically(Action action, TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            action();
            await Task.Delay(interval, token);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That solved it for me. Works like a charm, thank you!